# Tomcat 8 and Java 8: High Memory usage

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, java-8, tomcat8, java-opts

**Background**:

```
Windows Server 2012 R2- 64 bit
16 GB RAM
Tomcat 8
Java 8
```

I am running a java application on Tomcat 8. I am facing high memory usage problem. The memory usage goes up to  95% and server crashes. No problem with CPU usage.

I am setting JAVA_OPTS in `tomcat\bin\catalina.bat`

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG% -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:+UseParallelGC"
```

NOTE: XMS and XMX is set from catalina UI.

**I understand, there is no PermGen concept in Java 8** so I tried below JAVA_OPTS with -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m too

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG% -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -XX:+UseParallelGC"
```

But no luck.

Interesting thing:

The memory used by tomcat process remain around 3.5 GB but memory usage goes up  to 15 GB. All the remaining processes add up to 1 GB only. I have no clue which process is consuming remaining 9-10 GB.

The system memory goes up and here is the snap.
[image: Task Manager]

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong:The Permgen space has been removed completely from Java 8 and metaspace has been introduced. Metaspace uses native memory of OS so it is possible that the undiscovered 9-10 GBs are being eaten up by Metaspace. If this theory is correct. Can someone tell me how to restrict Metaspace. I have already tried XX:MaxMetaspaceSize... thanks

Comment: you need to post more deteiled stats. what memory usage goes up (system or vm?) which memory figures (rss, buffers, virtual, ...). anything that might be useful.

Comment: Added snapshot of system's task manager.

Comment: so it's not really the java process itself allocating the memory. you could try sysinternals process explorer and rammap tools.

Comment: Are you suggesting, there is nothing wrong with the tomcat or java. Is it something to do with other System process which is eating up the RAM??

Comment: that is a possibility

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the VM we were using. There were some update processes which use to keep the VM busy.